# select count(*) query for many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not have a complicated problem, just because my English is not good, I can not find a solution, please help me with this question and below. **And type the ready query for me. Please**

We have:

```
Posts: id, name, status('enable','disable')
Type: id, name
PostType: PostID, ProjectTypeID
```

I want to get the number of `enable` posts from each `Type` item.

> This is almost my answer but I want the number based on type items!
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395372/14823479

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: @D-Shih Okay, just please check my questions again.

Comment: Still not clear could you show us some sample and expect result?

Comment: Trivial JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT().

Answer (score 1):

As Akina said, this is a trivial (*classic*, if you don't like the term) query. Just remember the order of the operations:

```
SELECT what_you_want_to_select/count
FROM a_table
JOIN relation_table ON a_table.pk = relation_table.fk1
JOIN another_table ON another_table.pk = relation_table.fk2
WHERE status_condition
GROUP BY the_type
```

Can you complete this query with the correct syntax?